# Reading from CSV into Array

Tags: csv, opencsv

I'm trying to read a list of numbers from a csv file and place the values into an array like the following, but it's not working. It's strange that this used to work but now it doesn't.

```
matProps = pd.DataFrame.from_csv("A1008_SI.csv", index_col=None, encoding='utf-8')

Em =       matProps.Value[0]     # Elastic modulus ***[MPa]***
Su =       matProps.Value[1]     # UTS ***[MPa]***
sigmaf =   matProps.Value[2]     # fatigue strength coefficient ***[MPa]***
b =        matProps.Value[3]     # fatigue strength exponent
epsilonf = matProps.Value[4]     # fatigue ductility coefficient
c =        matProps.Value[5]     # fatigue ductility exponent
K =        matProps.Value[6]     # Cyclic strength coefficient ***[MPa]***
n =        matProps.Value[7]     # Cyclic strain hardening exponent`
```

I get:
AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'from_csv'

I tried using various read csv commands but that doesn't seem to be putting them in the array.